# For exC++ inserting into a list the object being pointed to by an iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator

let's say that you have an iterator pointing to an object in a list and you want to write a function that will copy whatever object the iterator is pointing to into another specified list. is this possible?

for example

```
 std::list<Customer> customer;
 for (customer=customers.begin(); customer!=customers.end(); ++customer){
     std::list<Inventory>::iterator tool;
     for (tool=inventory.begin(); tool!=inventory.end(); ++tool){
          tool->addToWaitlist( customer );
      }
 }
```

where

```
 void addToWaitlist(std::list<Customer>::iterator customer){ 
            std::list<Customer>::iterator person;
            if (!wait_list.empty()){
                    for (person=wait_list.begin(); person!=wait_list.end(); ++person){
                            // Add customer with respect to time stamp
                            //if ( customer.getTime() <= person->getTime() ){
                            //      wait_list.insert( person, customer );
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    // Add first person to wait list
                    wait_list.push_back( customer );
            }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  Please show your code.

Comment: _"is this possible?"_ Yes, it's possible. Did you face any particular problem doing so? Show the relevant problematic code and all error messages verbatim please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
// given some T and the following lists
list<T> l1, l2;
list<T>::iterator objit=l1.begin();    // picked the first item in l1 since it's easy

// copy the item to l2
l2.push_back(*objit);
```

Comment: Not that straight forward when dealing with a list of pointers.

Comment: If you say so. It works out the same. And nobody in the OP were pointers mentioned, so I'm not sure what exactly is your point.

Comment: It's not the same. If you have a list of pointers then a straight pointer copy will only take a shallow copy so you essentially end up having two pointers that point to the same object rather than taking a deep copy.